# Asymptote of $\sum_{j=1}^{n}(-1)^{j} \phi (j)$

Tags: number-theory, limits

How do you compute the asymptotic behavior, not sure if I'm wording this correctly,  of $\sum_{j=1}^{n}(-1)^{j} \phi (j)$ where $\phi$ is the euler totient function, as in $\mathcal{O}(\sum_{j=1}^{n}(-1)^{j} \phi (j))= \mathcal{O}(?)$. I've looked at graphs of this sum for n up to 40000 and it's obviously decreasing with negative concavity but I don't really know what to do from there.

Comment: What is your $\phi$ function? Is is the [*totient function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you are working with the alternating sum of the totient function, tweaking [this calculation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1259603/show-that-sum-n-le-x-phi-n-fracx22-zeta2-ox-log-x) gives a good asymptotics. Indeed, using the formula $ \phi(n) = \sum_{md = n} m \mu(d)$ we can write

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n \leq x} (-1)^n \phi(n)
&= \sum_{md \leq x} (-1)^{md} m \phi(d) \\
&= \sum_{d \leq x} \phi(d) \sum_{m \leq x/d} (-1)^{md} m.
\end{align*}

Now dividing the case according to whether $d$ is even or odd, we find that for any positive integer $k$,

$$ \sum_{m \leq k} (-1)^{md} m = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2}k^2 + \mathcal{O}(k), & \text{if } d \text{ is even.} \\
\mathcal{O}(k), & \text{if } d \text{ is odd.}
\end{cases} $$

Thus, by splitting the sum according to the parity of $d$ and using the fact that $\mu$ is non-zero only for square-free integers, we have

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n \leq x} (-1)^n \phi(n)
&= \sum_{\substack{ d \leq x \\ d \text{ : odd}}} \text{[to be typeset]} + \sum_{\substack{ d = 2d' \leq x \\ d' \text{ : odd}}} \text{[to be typeset]} \\
&= - \sum_{\substack{d' \leq x/2 \\ d' \text{ : odd}}} \mu(d') \frac{x^2}{2(2d')^2} + \mathcal{O}(x \log x) \\
&= - \frac{x^2}{8} \sum_{d' \text{ : odd}} \frac{\mu(d')}{(d')^2} + \mathcal{O}(x \log x) \\
&= - \frac{1}{6\zeta(2)}x^2 + \mathcal{O}(x \log x).
\end{align*}

Calculation up to $x = 4000$ seems to suggest that the error term is $\mathcal{O}(x)$, but I have no idea how to push it down to this bound.