# How can I prove: $\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\phi(n)}{n^2} = \frac{\log x}{\zeta(2)}+\frac{C}{\zeta(2)} + A + O\left(\frac{\log x}{x}\right)$

Tags: number-theory

The problem is that prove that $$\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\phi(n)}{n^2} = \frac{\log x}{\zeta(2)}+\frac{C}{\zeta(2)} + A + O\left(\frac{\log x}{x}\right)$$ 
where $C$ is Euler's constant and $A = \sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{\mu(n)\log n}{n^2}$

---

The following is things I did try:

$$\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\phi(n)}{n^2} = \sum_{n\leq x}\frac{1}{n}\frac{\phi(n)}{n} =\\ 
\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{d\mid n} \frac{\mu(d)}{d} = \sum_{q\leq x}\frac{1}{q} \sum_{d\leq x} \frac{x}{q}\frac{\phi(d)}{d^2} =\\
\sum_{q\leq x}\frac{1}{q}\left( \frac{1}{\zeta(2)} + O\left(\frac{q}{x}\right) \right) = \frac{\log x}{\zeta(2)} + \frac{C}{\zeta(2)}  + O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) + \sum_{q\leq x}\frac{1}{q} O\left(\frac{q}{x}\right) $$

Here $\mu$ is the Möbius function and $\phi$ is the Euler totient function.

Comment: What is $\mu(n)$?

Comment: @unseen_rider function mu is mobius function

Comment: [Summation by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts) and using [$\sum_{k\leq x} \phi(k) = \frac{x^2}{2\zeta(2)} + O(x\log(x))$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1259603/show-that-sum-n-le-x-phi-n-fracx22-zeta2-ox-log-x?rq=1) looks like a promising route. It might also be useful to know that [$\sum_{k\leq x} \frac{1}{k} = \log(x) + C + O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to obtain the estimate OP wanted. We have in fact ($+A$ should be corrected to $-A$):
$$
\sum_{n\leq x }\frac{\phi(n)}{n^2}= \frac6{\pi^2}(\log x+C) -A +O\left(\frac{\log x}x\right).
$$

The OP had a good start indeed:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{d\mid n} \frac{\mu(d)}{d}&=\sum_{d\leq x} \sum_{n\leq x, \ d|n} \frac{1}{n} \frac{\mu(d)}{d}\\
&=\sum_{d\leq x}\sum_{q\leq \frac xd} \frac1{dq} \frac{\mu(d)}d \ \ \ \textrm{(Substitution $n=dq$)}\\
&=\sum_{d\leq x}\frac{\mu(d)}{d^2} \sum_{q\leq \frac xd} \frac 1q \\
&=\sum_{d\leq x}\frac{\mu(d)}{d^2} \left( \log\frac xd + C + O\left(\frac dx\right)\right)\\
&=\sum_{d\leq x}\frac{\mu(d)}{d^2}( \log x + C) - \sum_{d\leq x}\frac{\mu(d)\log d}{d^2} + O\left(\frac{\log x}x\right)\\
&=\frac{6}{\pi^2}(\log x+ C)-A +O\left(\frac{\log x}x\right) \ \ \ \textrm{(Replacing $\sum_{d\leq x}$ by $\sum_{d=1}^{\infty}$ contributes $O\left(\frac{\log x}x\right)$)}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Let we implement the approach suggested by Winther in the comments, with a minor variation.
[From](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1259603/show-that-sum-n-le-x-phi-n-fracx22-zeta2-ox-log-x?rq=1)
$$ \sum_{n\leq x}\varphi(n) = \frac{x^2}{2\zeta(2)}+O(x\log x) \tag{1}$$
and [Abel's summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula) we get:

$$ \sum_{n\geq x}\frac{\varphi(n)}{n^2}=\frac{1}{2\zeta(2)}+O\left(\frac{\log x}{x}\right)+2\int_{1}^{x}\left( \frac{u^2}{2\zeta(2)}+O(u\log u)\right)\frac{du}{u^3}\tag{2} $$
and the claim readily follows by rearranging terms.

Comment: The $O(u\log u)$ term gives $O(1)$ in the result, so more precision is required.